# Underlined breakable multi line with text under

Tags: multline

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names, table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\emone}[1]{\textcolor{RoyalBlue3}{\stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\scriptsize M1}}}

\begin{document}
    \emone{this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a textthis is a text this is a text this is a text}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to put some text underline. I made breakable underlined text by some package and for the text under it I used stackengine package but it is a hbox type so it is not possible to break it in multi
line. So pls share with me your comment on this pic and give your solutions.

[image]

Comment: No. We need more context. And include all your code.

Comment: i did it, is it possible to check it again?! big thanks for your time

Comment: What are you using around this? Or are these `\emone`s just put on its own (like in a math display)?

Comment: i am working on analysis on sentences. Every word has different rule. I want to type word rules underline. "english modifier 1=emone"

Comment: Can you provide a visual of what you mean by a multi-line text looks like to you? And how the underline should like, together with the placement of the text underneath? You really need to spoon-feed us information.

Comment: i added another image. this text was made by myself but i can do that in a multi line. another important thing is about being NP should be underline breakable and in next line should be same as pic 1st.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you mean by "underline breakable." The image you show doesn't show any multi-line content, so it's difficult to guess how a multi-line entry (sentence?) should be broken, together with all the content underneath it.

Comment: I added another image. My problem is  about stackengine package. When i use ulem pack i can make multiple underline but when i use stackunder i can not do that any more and text continue in stright way as i give you an example in sample code. Any way i send another image. Pls run my code you will see the result.

Comment: I understand. Why not break these manually? It seems like, when the line breaks, you want something else written underneath it (`cont NP` instead of `NP`, say). Is there anything that would prevent you from doing it manually?

Comment: Yes correct. sometimes NP will be longer than 2 lines. So i need to do that by program to make sure everything is true and focus on the main purposes not graphics