# wrapping a box in multi line

Tags: wrap

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{ulem}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{4}

\begin{document}
    

    \stackunder{\uline{this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text}}{text1}
    


    \uline
    {   
        \stackunder{\stackunder{ text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this}{\uline{text1}}}{text 2} \\
        \stackunder{ text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this}{Cont. text1}\\
        \stackunder{ text this a text this a text this a text this a text this a text this}{Cont. text1}
    }
\end{document}
```

I am trying to make underlined text with some text under. for that i have used stackengine package to put some text under that line. but it is a hbox type and it is not possible to be wrap automatically and it should be updated under text also

I can do that manually but in most cases those stuff which i want to be underlined with text under it is long. another thing it should be capable to do nested underlined text also so pls help me to solve this issue

[image]

Comment: Related: [Underlined breakable multi line with text under](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575433/5764)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point. With this simple solution you have to manually mark the words where the tag is to be placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand\tag[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #1\\
    \makebox[0pt]{#2}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\uline{A long, long sentence that goes \tag{beyond}{sentence}
the end of line, and even then does not stop, but 
\tag{goes on}{sent.\ continued}, and on, and on, and on.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. but still there is 3 problem: first of all i can't use another \uline as a nested command in the main \uline (i tried it but still i have the same problem like what is happened for long text inside the fist line of my picture) and second one is how i can  put this tabular in the middle of line and 3rd one is how i can do wrapping automatically